# The correct usage of every (other/second/third/fourth etc.)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

According to the [Collins Dictionary's definition](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/every-other-day-every-second-day-etc):

> If something happens **every other day** or **every second day**, for example, **it happens one day, then does not happen the next day, then happens the day after that,** and so on. You can also say that something happens every third week, every fourth year, and so on.

It would mean that if I see my friend today, then tomorrow a one-day-break, then the day after tomorrow I see her and it continues  the same way, I can say each one of the sentences below interchangeably:

> 1.a. I see my friend **on alternate days**. 
>   1.b. I see my friend **every other day**. 
>   1.c. I see my friend **every second day**.

Also, if I see my friend today, then tomorrow and the day after tomorrow a two-day-break, then after two days I see her again and it continues the same way, I can say each one of the sentences below in an interchangeable way without any difference in meaning:

> 2.a. I see my friend **every two days**.

Or

I don't know if second is used here or in the former meaning (I mean: on alternate days)?

> 2.b. I see my friend **every second day**.

If "**every second**" is used in the meaning of "on alternate", then here I must use "every third":

> 2.c. I see my friend **every third day**.

And the rest is history.

On the other hand, someone else in this [thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82902/i-see-someone-every-two-days) says:

> "Every two days" is the same as "every other day." If you wanted to describe a two-day break, it would be "every third day.

This is what is not clear either in the similar thread on the forum, or in the Collins's definition.

Please let me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is, but I see no problem with 1a,1b,1c.

2a, and 2b however:

> if I see my friend today, then tomorrow and the day after tomorrow a two-day-break, then after two days I see her again and it continues the same way, I can say each one of the sentences below in an interchangeable way without any difference in meaning

A **two day** break, and then seeing the friend on the **day after**, is every **third** day, (one day in three).

Every second day means a 2 day cycle, which is every other day

So 2c would be correct. (and that other thread would be correct too)

Attempting to be clear:

Every day with a visit = 1 day cycle = every single day = every day

One day empty, one day with a visit = 2 day cycle = every second day = once every two days = *every other day*

Two days empty, one day with a visit = 3 day cycle = every third day = once every three days

Three days empty, one day with a visit = 4 day cycle = every fourth day = once every four days

(the *once* can usually be omitted)

Comment: If I'm nit mistaken @Smock, based on your statements, **every other = every second** and **every two... = every third**. Also, **every three = every fourth**. Do you confirm?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure how you've read it that way. Just count the total number of days involved. 3 days with one visit is every third day. 2 days with a visit on one of the days is every two days

Comment: Also, saying "I see my friend one day in three" is not the same as "every three days."  "Every three days" is a repeating pattern, while "one day in three" means that for each period of three days, you saw your friend only one, but not necessarily the same day each period.

Comment: Please have a look on the picture @Smock.

Comment: @JRodge01 True, but every three days does equate one day in three, it's just specific about always being the same pattern, but I'll take it out if it causes ambiguity.

Comment: @A-friend Picture 2 is **not** every two days

Comment: @A-friend Picture 2 is not correct, at least for US usage of "every two days".

Comment: @JRodge01 do you think it would be better to remove all the *once*'s ?